# How do I get child view id from parent's OnClickListener?

Tags: java, android, xml, onclicklistener

I have a simple LinearLayout with multiply Buttons inside.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/parent">
   <Button android:id="@+id/child_1">
   <Button android:id="@+id/child_2">
   <Button android:id="@+id/child_3">
   ...
</LinearLayout>
```

I set OnClickListener to parent LinearLayout and when I click on any child Buttons onClick method is called. How I can know id of clicked Button?

Note. I don't want to set OnClickListener to each Button or add **onClick="someMethod"** in xml layout.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will work

make your activity implement View.OnClickListener interface

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      Button child1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.child_1);
      child1.setOnClickListener(this);
      Button child2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.child_2);
      child1.setOnClickListener(this);
  }
}
```

and then override onClick method

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.child_1:
                // do something when child 1 is clicked
              break;
            case R.id.child_2:
                // do something when child 2 is clicked
              break;
        }
}
```

If you have many buttons then I would suggest a ListView/ RecyclerView and handle the click once based on the position

Comment: Unfortunately **View v** will return parent LinearLayout element instead Button as expected.

Comment: It's just an example. I want to learn how do I can access to child views like it available in JavaScript via **event**.